# How to handle the Click output in the Table

Tags: libgdx, clicklistener

I have a table and add all the button, below is the button code, it is repeat to make the level0 - 9 button. When I click the button, it will save their number into the Preferences (prefs) and go to the next screen, but all the button also save the last number (10) into the Preferences (prefs). How can I improve it?

```
for (level = 0; level < 10;level++) {
    levelbutton[level].getLabel().setFontScale(1 * witdh / 540, 1 * height / 960);
    levelbutton[level].addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            prefs.putInteger("Level",level);
            prefs.flush();
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(basicGame);
        }
    });
        leveltable.add(levelbutton[level]).width(170*witdh/540).height(80*height/960);
        leveltable.row();
    }
```

Comment: Please don't edit something like *"Solved"* into your answer. Instead, accept the answer you find most useful by clicking the check-mark next to it. This will properly mark the question as solved on a system level.

Answer (score 0):

Actor class having a `name` data member that can be used for identification. You can use this for your requirement.

```
for (level = 0; level < 10;level++) {

    levelbutton[level].getLabel().setFontScale(1 * witdh / 540, 1 * height / 960);
    levelbutton[level].setName(String.valueOf(level));
    levelbutton[level].addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            Actor target = event.getTarget();
            String targetName = target.getName();
            if(targetName !=null) {

                int levelNum=Integer.parseInt(targetName);
                prefs.putInteger("Level",levelNum);
                prefs.flush();
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(basicGame);
            }
        }
    });
    leveltable.add(levelbutton[level]).width(170*witdh/540).height(80*height/960);
    leveltable.row();
}
```

**EDIT**

Yes `getListenerActor()` is better option, that returns attached actor of listener.

```
target = event.getListenerActor();
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I change it to 
target = event.getListenerActor();
It is more stable for my situation. Thanks for your hits.